# Implement Pagination in ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, pagination, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I searched, but did't really found articles on how to implement pagination logic in an ASP.NET WebAPI Core 2.1 application...

I have the following

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[EnableCors("AllowMyOrigin")]
public class EntriesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly EntriesContext _context;

    public EntriesController(EntriesContext context) {
        _context = context;

        if (_context.Entries.Count() == 0) {
            _context.Entries.Add(new Entry { From = "default", To = "default" });
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<Entry>> GetAll() {
        return _context.Entries.ToList();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetEntry")]
    public ActionResult<Entry> GetById(long id) {
        var item = _context.Entries.Find(id);
        if (item == null) { return NotFound(); }
        return item;
    }
```

Now, I want my entries to be paginated using new params **`page`** and **`pageSize`**. Say

```
/api/entries?pageSize=3&page=2
```

Should I use the `GetAll()` method by adding some http params to it, or rather create a new method? There are no much sense to use `page` without `pageSize`, how do I manage this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you can default you `pageSize` value to something:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<List<Entry>> GetAll(int? page = null, int? pageSize = 10) 
{
    if (!page.HasValue) {
        return _context.Entries.ToList();
    }

    // do you pagination here
}
```

But you also may look at [OData](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/odatateam/2018/07/03/asp-net-core-odata-now-available/), it seems to be your case. It will allow you to query your data using http params, e.g.: `/api/Entires?$skip=5&$top=5`

Comment: the OData is not available as I understand for the .NET Core 2.1 ? it seems broken in 2.1... https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1447

Comment: @Serge it should work generally, though it may have some issues. Also provided issue is closed

Comment: I'd advised against OData. A lot of big companies have ditched its use, Netflix for example. Even Microsoft is questioning its future. Its a proprietary tech that is really struggling to gain ground.

Comment: Tx, do you know if there is a decent OData server side + client side that work together in an ASP.NET Core (with EF Core) and a .NET Standard based client (Uno platform)?

Answer (score 25):

There are libraries, such as [X.PagedList](https://www.nuget.org/packages/X.PagedList.Mvc.Core) you can use. Frankly, pagination is pretty straight-forward, so you may not even need that. All you need to know is the page number, page size, and total number of results. The page number obvious comes from the request, and the page size can as well, if you want it customizable, or you can hard-code it.

```
public ActionResult<List<Entry>> GetAll(int page = 1, int size = 10)
```

Then, you can use `Skip` and `Take` to get the data for a particular page:

```
var query = _context.Entries;
var entries = await query.Skip((page - 1) * size).Take(size).ToListAsync();
var count = await query.CountAsync();
```

Then, all you need to know is the total number of pages, which can be calculated simply via:

```
var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceil(count / (float)size);
```

From that, you can calculate anything else you need, i.e.:

```
var firstPage = 1; // obviously
var lastPage = totalPages;
var prevPage = page > firstPage ? page - 1 : firstPage;
var nextPage = page < lastPage ? page + 1 : lastPage;
```

Comment: I think you can await `entries` and `count` with `await Task.WhenAll(people, count);` instead of awaiting it sequentially?

Comment: @koral, DbContext is not thread safe, so you'll get an exception

Answer (score -1):

I've just created a PagingTagHelper for ASP.NET Core Razor pages to render paging control easily with just the basic parameters, the simplest setup looks like below:

```
<paging total-records="Model.TotalRecords" page-no="Model.PageNo">
</paging>
```

all you need is to provide total records and page number for it to run. The default query string parameters are "p" for page number and "s" for page size, however, it is customizable/localizable, you can change all the settings according to your own requirements.

you can install it from nuget:

```
Install-Package LazZiya.TagHelpers -Version 1.0.2
```

then you need to add the tag helper to the _ViewImports.cshtml file:

```
@addTagHelper *, LazZiya.TagHelpers
```

http://ziyad.info/en/articles/21-Paging_TagHelper_for_ASP_NET_Core

more documentations and live demo will be available soon.