# Odata asp.net core 2.2 web api pagination

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

Is there any way to handle page size from the query parameter sent by the client. And not as default in the code as Enablequery(Pagesize = 100)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement Pagination in ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52331318/implement-pagination-in-asp-net-core-2-1-web-api)

Comment: Not really what i need is how to set the pagesize from a query parameter if it is sent by the client or apply a default if nothing is sent by client. Because in odata documentation they show only default pagesize. The purpose is to generate the pagination link from odata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to handle page size from the query parameter sent by the client. And not as default in the code as Enablequery(Pagesize = 100)

To achieve above requirement, you can try to create and use a customized EnableQueryAttribute, like below:

*In customized EnableQueryAttribute*

```
public class MyCustomQueryableAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
{
    public override IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        // dynamically set PageSize of ODataQuerySettings 
        // based on pagesize that client sent through querystring

        StringValues ps;

        // set default value to pagesize

        int pagesize = 2;

        if (queryOptions.Request.Query.TryGetValue("pagesize", out ps))
        {
            pagesize = int.Parse(ps);
        }

        var result = queryOptions.ApplyTo(queryable, new ODataQuerySettings { PageSize = pagesize });
        return result;
    }
}
```

*In ODataController action*

```
[MyCustomQueryable]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok(_db.Books);
}
```

*Test Result*

[image]